# Can I target allies with utility powers without having line of effect to them?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, targeting

The rules for "Seeing and Targeting" (PHB, p273) specifically mention that

> You need line of effect to any target you attack and to any space in which you wish to create an effect.

However, that does *not* mention anything about line of effect being necessary for powers that aren't attacks and don't target spaces, such as beneficial utility powers. Can I use a power like that on an ally that I don't have line of effect to, but am aware of and have them within the range of the power?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You need line of effect.

From the RC on targets, p107:

> **Line of Effect**
> ... Unless otherwise noted, there must be line of effect between the origin square of an effect and its intended target for that target to be affected. ...

The only difference between effects that target allies as opposed to foes or creatures is that allies can ignore the effect if they want.

From the RC on targets, p106:

> **Ally** means a companion of the power's user. When a power defines a target as an ally, the ally is free to ignore the power's effects. ... In contrast, a creature targeted by an ally's power cannot ignore its effect if the power targets a "creature" or "creatures," instead of an "ally" or "allies".

There are some differences between effects that explicitly target allies and those that don't, but they have nothing to do with line of effect. A power's origin must have line of effect to its targets, regardless of whether they are allies are foes, unless the power *explicitly* waives that requirement.

Comment: Thank you, I should probably get Rules Compendium myself.

Comment: @UristMcDorf I wouldn't say that it's necessary to play, but if you find yourself running into ambiguities in the rules a lot it can definitely be a worthwhile investment. It's basically the rules from the PHB, plus additional rules/mechanics from later books, collected together with the benefit of a couple years' hindsight and errata.